# Describing the topology of the set $\{e^{i\theta} : -\pi<\theta \leq \pi\}$

Tags: general-topology, complex-numbers

The question asks to describe some topological features of the set $\{e^{i\theta} : -\pi<\theta \leq \pi\}$.

More precisely, to explain whether the set is open, closed, neither or both and also whether or not it is bounded or if its connected?

After some research, I came to the conclusion that the graph would just be of a unit circle. Although, based on that knowledge, how can I know whether or not this set is open, closed, or neither?

Comment: What do you mean by shading, and what regions are you describing? Like you said, the given set is just the unit circle in $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Are you familiar with complex exponents? $e^{i\theta}=\cos(\theta)+i\sin(\theta)$. Try plugging in a few values for $\theta$, and you'll see it is *just* the unit circle, not anything  to be shaded in.

Comment: $-\pi<\theta \leq \pi$ just tells you how the circle is oriented, and that it is one complete revolution.

Comment: Open, closed in which space?

Comment: In Complex space

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The set is of course exactly the unit circle $S^1=\{z \in \Bbb C\mid |z|=1\}$: all $e^{i\theta}$ have length 1 and all argument values from $(-\pi,\pi]$ occur (so no gaps, or skipped points).

The set $S^1$ is the continuous image of $[-\pi,pi]$ under the continuous function $t \to e^{it}$, so as closed intervals are compact and connected in $\Bbb R$, so is $S^1$ in $\Bbb C$. Being compact, it's also closed there (and by consequence not open, as $\Bbb C$ is connected, although it's clear geometrically that no open ball in $\Bbb C$ sits inside the circle, so its interior is empty).